# How to edit DMARC report message?

Tags: postfix, opendkim

There is a mail server (postfix), which has DKIM, SPF and DMARC policies configured. 
All of them are PASSED, system works perfect.

As an administrator, I receive these kind of letters everyday:

```
Subject: Report Domain: mydomain.com, example.com Report-ID
```

and the content message like this:

```
Find attached the DMARC Aggregate Report.
```

Does my mail server also send reports to other mail servers? 
How can I edit content of message? 
 
For example, I want to write:

```
This DMARC report is generated automatically
```

Answer (score 1):

> There is a mail server (postfix), which has DKIM, SPF and DMARC policies configured.

Being *configured* to support those protocols can mean two separate things:

1. The server IP address is added to the domain's SPF list, the email software is signing outbound emails with DKIM, and the domain has a proper DMARC policy set. All this is done so that emails sent by the server can be validated by others; or
2. The server is configured to validate *incoming* emails. I.e., to do SPF checks, to verify DKIM signatures, and to apply any DMARC policies configured by a sender's domain owner. Optionally, the server can be configured to generate and send out DMARC report to interested parties.

I'm assuming the latter.

> As an administrator, I receive these kind of letters everyday

Those are DMARC report generated by *other* email servers and sent to you.

> Does my mail server also send reports to other mail servers?

As far as I know, no email software does that by default. So unless you configured Postfix to record DMARC check results and send out emails, the answer is *no*.

> How can I edit content of message?

DMARC reports have a specific format. The report itself is a XML file, generated by specialized software, and there's no reason to change that. You should be able to pass parameters to the DMARC report generation tools to change a few values -- for example, your organization name, and domain.